# getting the radius from a data point plotted on a radialLine

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In short, I have a spiral plot and dates are mapped on to this. This works fine but I now want to map date ranges on this same spiral. This spiral is produced using d3.radialLine. I can get the angle of each data point from using math.atan2(x,y), but how can I get the radius of each data point?

Comment: You mean radius of point with known coordinates (x,y) from center point ?

Comment: yeah, that's right

Comment: I believe it would be along the lines of:
`radius = math.sqrt(((x-0)*(x-0))+((y-0)*(y-0)))`

Answer (score 2):

`Math.hypot` calculates the distance between two points:

```
const distance = Math.hypot(ax - bx, ay - by);
```

Similar to:

```
const dx = ax - bx;
const dy = ay - by;
const distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works: `radius = Math.sqrt(((x-0)*(x-0))+((y-0)*(y-0)))`.
However, if there is a more elegant way to write this let me know

Comment: `radius = Math.hypot(x, y)` if the coordinates of the center are 0,0. Otherwise: `radius = Math.hypot(x - cx, y - cy)`

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky - seems like a useful answer; why not post it ?